# Losing sync from random noise bursts on ADSL line

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, sync

I live in Lebanon and have a connection of 2 Mbps ADSL.

At random times, I get a sudden high amount of errors and I start losing sync (internet going on and off for like 20mins or just once). The uptime of the DSL never reaches 20 hours+. I'm only like 1.5 km to 2 km away from exchange. I have a phone socket in each room but I only use one for the phone (with a filter) and the router (without a filter) in another room.

Here are my stats:

```
Uptime: 0 days, 6:50:33
DSL Type:   G.992.1 annex A
Bandwidth (Up/Down) [kbps/kbps]:    484 / 2.042
Data Transferred (Sent/Received) [kB/kB]:   0,00 / 0,00
Output Power (Up/Down) [dBm]:   12,0 / 17,5
Line Attenuation (Up/Down) [dB]:    18,0 / 32,0
SN Margin (Up/Down) [dB]:   9,0 / 14,5
Vendor ID (Local/Remote):   TMMB / BDCM
Loss of Framing (Local/Remote): 19 / 0
Loss of Signal (Local/Remote):  5 / 0
Loss of Power (Local/Remote):   0 / 0
Loss of Link (Remote):  0
Error Seconds (Local/Remote):   136 / 0
FEC Errors (Up/Down):   0 / 0
CRC Errors (Up/Down):   254 / 260
HEC Errors (Up/Down):   118 / 31
```

If you're wondering, I have interleaving off; when it used to be on, I get sudden high FEC errors(400k+) , speed decreases to 1 Mbps and sometimes loss of sync.

So what could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have other telephones on the other (unfiltered) sockets in the house/building? You say you only use the filter for the socket with the modem/router; if there are other phones in the other sockets then this may be the cause.

Comment: uh no,I don't.I only got one phone with a filter in a socket,the router in another socket without a filter.

Comment: What make and model modem/router do you have? Is your Internet ADSL or VDSL?

Comment: ADSL,thomson tg585 v7

Comment: How are you connecting the modem to the wall? Do you have a special socket for modems (often labeled for VDSL) or do you have a special cable? Not knowing the Lebanon phone socket standard I don't know... pictures would be helpful to understand your setup :)

Comment: http://s12.postimg.org/jdtp5tonx/IMG_20150823_175738.jpg

Comment: The cream/white device, is that a lebanon telephone filter? You may want to change the filter (or at least add one to the socket where your modem is) or it may be a problem between your house and the exchange. I (in the UK) had drops in my Internet and it turned out to be a cable outside my flat had corroded so the connection was on and off).

Comment: No,that's the cable for the router,and the white device converts the cable into 2 pins(much like any device power pins)so it could be plugged to the wall,I don't know if it's a filter,there's nothing written on it,but could it be the problem?FYI,Lebanese telephone filters comes with shorter and closer pins.